# Measurability of a set constructed from another measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $E$ be a measurable subset of the real numbers. I define $\sigma(E) = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x-y \in E\}$. I would like to prove that this set $\sigma(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R^2}$, but when I write down the equation $\mu(\sigma(E) \cap A) + \mu(\sigma(E) \cap A^c) = \mu(\sigma(E))$ for arbitrary $A$,I get stuck. I would like help on how to tackle this situation of measurability in a different space.

A similar question of this kind was that if $f,g$ are measurable functions then so is $h(x,y)=f(x-y)g(y)$ in a higher dimensional space. I had trouble writing down $h(x,y)>\alpha$ in this case, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$,and decomposing it in terms of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Surely $\alpha \in \mathbf R$? Also, a product of measurable functions is measurable. Can you show $g(y)$ and $f(x-y)$ are measurable?

Comment: @RickSanchez How would you show that $f(x-y)$ is measurable? That would involve solving the first question above, right? And thank you Bungo for the correction.

Comment: Is $f$ Borel measurable? If so, it should be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for the first question: Let $f(x,y) = x-y.$ Then $f$ is continuous. If $E\subset \mathbb R$ were a Borel set, then $f^{-1}(E)$ would be a Borel set. So you'll be done if you can show that if $F\subset \mathbb R$ has one-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0,$ then $f^{-1}(F)$ has two-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0.$

Comment: How does your last sentence help?

Comment: Thank you, @zhw. I would like to know how to show that if $F$ has $1D$ Lebesgue measure zero, then $f^{-1}(F)$ has two dimensional measure zero. Does this follow from the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz in some manner?

Comment: @RickSanchez Every Lebesgue measurable set is equal to the union of a Borel measurable set and a set of Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг If $a \in F$, then $f^{-1}(a)$ is the diagonal line $y=x−a$. So $f^{-1}(F)$ is a union of such lines. If you rotate the set $f^{-1}(F)$ by $45$ degrees about the origin (which is a rigid motion, hence preserves measure) so that the lines become vertical, you will obtain the set $(1/\sqrt{2})F\times \mathbb R$, and it should not be too hard to show that the two-dimensional measure of the latter is zero whenever the one-dimensional measure of $F$ is zero.